# Python socket connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, what is problem?

Tags: python, sockets

I have some *GPS Tracker Devices* that send their states to server when I sent **"LOAD"** command, all things is good and I get response, **but after 1 minute i get this error** :

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

can someone help to solve this?

**here is my server codes :**

````
import datetime
import socket
import threading

host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 4018
connedcted_devices = set()
output_imei_list = set()

def get_clients(sock, conn):
    _msg = "LOAD"
    message = 'message ' + str(_msg)
    encodedMessage = bytes(message, 'utf-8')
     
    output_imei = conn.recv(1024)
    print(output_imei)

    if output_imei in output_imei_list:
        print("Connection already exists")
    else:
        output_imei_list.add(output_imei)
        # print(output_imei_list)
        connedcted_devices.add(conn)
        print("New connection added to cnn_list")
        conn.sendall(encodedMessage)


def receive_response(conn):
    # counter = 0
    while True:
        # if counter == 50 :
        #     break
        
        # conn.settimeout(60) # Set timeout to 60 seconds
        encodedAckText = conn.recv(1024)
        ackText = encodedAckText.decode('utf-8')
        splitedTextList = ackText.split(",")
        list_len = len(splitedTextList)
        if list_len > 0:
            print(splitedTextList)

        # counter += 1
        # print(counter)  


def main():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.bind((host, port))
        print('socket binded')
        sock.listen()
        print('socket now listening')
        
        while True:
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            get_clients(sock, conn)
            
            if(len(connedcted_devices) > 0):
                for x in connedcted_devices:
                    threading.Thread(target=receive_response, args=(x,)).start()
         

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````

Comment: It is unclear what your code is supposed to do. It is unclear what the client does. But it is obvious that you don't handle `recv` returning `''` but instead expect the recv either blocks or returns valid payload.

Comment: Every time you get a new connection, you start a new thread for ALL the connections.  That's not right.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am really new, what is should do?

Comment: @TimRoberts you mean I should remove connection after start thread?

Comment: When the decoded response is an empty string (because the client has closed its end of the socket) then list_len == 1 because splitedTextList == ['']

Comment: You have an infinite loop because there's nothing that breaks out of the loop.

Comment: @CtrlZ How I can manage this?

Comment: @NEBEZ How about checking the length of data received?

Comment: When recv returns 0 bytes it means the connection was disconnected.

Comment: @CtrlZ by using ```if list_len > 5:
            print(splitedTextList)``` i could prevent [''] responses, but it seem connections are closed, How can I re run connections ?

Comment: @user253751 Thanks, true, I solved it. but how I prevent connetions disconnected?

Comment: When you get an `accept`, you launch a thread to handle that socket.  That thread should run until the socket disconnects (when `read` returns empty).  You don't have to keep starting it.  Meanwhile, the main thread goes back and calls `accept` again, which blocks until there is a new client.